# Can not test apache kafka official site commands using docker: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have run the apache kafka and prometheus using docker. I will attach the docker-compose and other configurations at the bottom of this post!

**Introduction:** First I should explain that each metric of kafka works well on prometheus. So there is no problem in the implementation and running of the images.

**Problem:** The only problem is where I want to test the stream (Producer, Broker and Consumer) following the tutorial of the [official site of apache kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart). But whenever I execute the commands found on the site, I faced with the `command not found error`, because I don't know where the files exactly are! As an example whenever I execute the `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` command I face with the following error:

> no such file or directory: bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh

**Attachments:**

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    links:
     - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_OPTS: -javaagent:/usr/app/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=7071:/usr/app/prom-jmx-agent-config.yml
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090/tcp
    volumes:
      - ./mount/prometheus:/etc/prometheus

    links:
      - kafka
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM wurstmeister/kafka

ADD prom-jmx-agent-config.yml /usr/app/prom-jmx-agent-config.yml
ADD jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.10.jar /usr/app/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar
```

**Question:** Is there any solution to find where are the original files are mapped in the created container and execute them?

Answer (score 1):

The quickstart on the Apache site never references Docker. Those scripts need downloaded (as part of Kafka), or you need to `docker exec` into the container to run them

However, Docker already starts Kafka and Zookeeper, so you wouldn't need to run those commands. You therefore could skip to writing your own producers/consumers without using any provided scripts

Comment: would you please give some examples and add them to your posts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to run. Like I said, Zookeeper doesn't need started, for example

Comment: what I want is monitoring wikipedia data's and give them as stream to kafka, but I stucked in the first step and don't know how to do that! I am also new to kafka and prometheus.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that myself without actually writing Producer code

Comment: I have tried to access to the scripts using `docker exec` as you said, but I didn't find them! Have you ever tried to access them?

Comment: The wiki should explain https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't